# SEP (Symantec Endpoint Protection) for C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, symantec

I am using Doscan.exe of SEP to scan files before uploading but there is no provision provided by SEP to generate a separate log file for each scanned file, so that's why I am not able to make sure whether the file is ok or not for uploading.

If anyone has a way to check this thing then please let me know.

I am using version 14.2

Thanks.

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.Arguments = " /ScanFile C:\\Users\\New Text Document (2).txt";
                start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\14.2.3332.1000.105\Bin\DoScan.exe";
                start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you able to generate the log file with required details ? If you open it, does it provide the requested informations ? If yes, just read and parse it with C# and upload your original file as you want. If no, DoScan probably outputs to console, maybe you can get results here ? But you must show us what you already did for that purpose, and tell us what you mean by "upload".

Comment: I want to scan files before uploading to server through my webpage using SEP. So if  the file is clean then I will proceed further for the uploading part otherwise I will discard that file.

Comment: That's the (very brief) summary of the requirement, not the attempts done to achieve it. We don't even know if the problem is related to SEP, or to C# to read results/output file, etc.

Comment: Its related to SEP not with the C# as I am looking for any alternative for my problem.

Comment: So maybe it's not the right website to use !